# Using len function inside function in bascom

Tags: avr, bascom

I am developing a huge code and I want to use functions to break it to more readable blocks and reuse them many times. the problem is that I should use len function in all of my functions and appears Bascom has some issues with it. Here is my sample code which fully contains the issue:

```
Declare Function Getlen(byval Str1 As String) As word
Dim Bvar As Byte
Bvar ="hello"
Do
Bvar =Getlen(bvar)
Bvar = Len(bvar)
Loop
End


Function Getlen(byval Str1 As String) As Word
   Getlen = Len(str1)
End Function
```

and here is the error which I get from Bascom compiler 
error 71,242,124, all on function call line, when I use

```
Bvar = Len(bvar)
```

it will work correctly.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You mixed data types. Byte Bvar cannot hold string hello. And your Function should be declared as Byte, not Word. Try this example in Bascom Simulator:

```
$regfile = "m8def.dat"
$crystal = 16000000
$baud = 9600
$hwstack = 64
$swstack = 0
$framesize = 64


Declare Function Getlen(byval Str1 As String) As Byte

Dim Mylen As Byte

Dim Mystring As String * 10 : Mystring = "hello"

Print Mystring

Mylen = Getlen(mystring)

Print "Mylen=" ; Mylen


Do

Input "Enter any name: " , Mystring

Mylen = Getlen(mystring)

Print "Mylen=" ; Mylen

Loop


Function Getlen(byval Str1 As String) As Byte
    Getlen = Len(str1)
End Function
```